# No WiFi networks - Fujitsu Lifebook on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows, wireless-networking

I lost ability to see WiFi networks on my laptop.

I already tryied:

- reinstall wifi driver
- reboot
- disable/enable from windows and from bios
- check for latest driver both by Windows and Fukitsu driver update

When i Use windows Network Diagnostic, I am getting recomendation "**Turn on Wireless capability**". There is no switch or keyboard combination for this laptop model (or I do not know any one).

Any ideas?
Model A1220 http://www.retrevo.com/search?q=Fujitsu+A1220&rt=sp&modelid=23577149

Comment: What's the series and model?

Comment: sometimes the button for wifi on computers is touch sensitive plastic over the wifi icon on the computer. have you tried seeing if they hid it there?

Comment: Lifebook A Serias A1220

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the [A1220 User's Guide](http://solutions.us.fujitsu.com/www/content/pdf/SupportGuides/A1220_UG_B6FJ-2881-01ENZ0-00.pdf) on page 138 there's a picture showing you where the wireless LAN on/off switch is.

[image: 2]

Comment: Thanks. Thay made everything to make it not noticable

Comment: @Sergey: No problem :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to go to `Settings > PC Info > Advanced System Settings > Remote` then click on `Enable Wi Fi`.